# H2 server suspends while debugging

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, junit, h2

I have a Spring application that starts the following in memory H2 database for JUnit tests:

```
db.jdbc.driver=org.h2.Driver
db.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:sampledb
db.jdbc.username=
db.jdbc.password=
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
```

I would like to easily debug when my JUnit tests are running and meantime browse database state, so before test suite I start H2 Server:

```
org.h2.tools.Server.createTcpServer("-tcpPort", "9092", "-tcpAllowOthers").start();
```

Unfortunately when I put any breakpoint that suspends all threads it also suspends H2 server thread, so I am not able to connect. I cannot start H2 server in different process because in memory database is not accessible from outside VM.

I understand that I can use other type of breakpoint (that suspends only current thread) but it's a kind of limitation. Have you found other solutions for such problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting the tcp server will not help here, as you're creating a memory database.

I would suggest starting a console instead in a **thread**, and in the same piece of code (using jdbc for example) open a connection to this database but do not close/release it.

Do this with this snippet: please add options like allow others according to H2 documentation (I suggest leaving this as it is for now)

```
org.h2.tools.Server.createWebServer().start();
```

Opening the database in a 2nd thread with jdbc/jooq will look like this (this is in Nashorn javascript but can be easily adapted to java):

```
var conn = (new org.h2.Driver()).connect('jdbc:h2:mem:sampledb',new java.util.Properties());
var DB = org.jooq.impl.DSL.using(conn, org.jooq.SQLDialect.H2);
```

Like this, the memory based database will not be accidentally closed and you'll be able to access it remotely. Putting it in a thread hopefully will guard you from breakpoints.

**Updates:** Based on discussion with original author of this question, the best solution is to open the memory based H2 in a separate process and provide a tcp server on it. This solves the issue, but is in a separate process.

Here's how to start the separate process:

```
java -jar h2-1.4.188.jar -tcp -tcpPort 9092 -baseDir mem:mydb
```

Here's the JDBC url to use: `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:mydb`

**IMPORTANT NOTE:** If all connections on this memory based db are closed, the content will disappear. So this method is to be used with caution. If you need persistence through your tests, please use a standard file-based H2 DB.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the web server works the same as tcp server. I am able to connect to the server using both methods: tcp protocol when started tcp server and web browser when started web server. The problem is that when debugger suspends all threads then the remote connection connection to the database is frozen. I think I will start a database and a tcp server in sepparate process and connect to it remotely from Junit tests.

Comment: if you do so, you will not be able to access the memory db from another process. I suggest you move to a file based db.

Comment: I will be able - using remote connection trough tcp protocol.
With a file based h2 database I am not able to connect to the same database simultaneously since a file is locked.

Comment: jdbc:h2:mem:sampledb means it's a memory database. you cannot access it using tcp protocol, but you can access it using the H2 console, provided it was started by the same JVM. this is the main point of my answer.

Comment: You are wrong. I've just successfully started in memory database in sepparate process, together with tcp server and successfully connected to it. Try out: `java -jar h2-1.4.188.jar -tcp -tcpPort 9092 -baseDir mem:mydb`. Then you can connect using jdbc `jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost:9092/mem:mydb`. Have fun :)

Comment: Basically what solves my problem is starting database in sepparate process. I tried to avoid that because it's a lot of effort to handle another process termination when my JVM finishes, etc. However nobody had better idea so I had to implement such logic. Thanks for your answers.

Comment: @Konrad I've updated the answer. I advise caution on memory based db. Good luck with your tests!

Answer (score 10):

Kind of an old question, but for those who happen to stumble over this thread and are looking for an easy answer:

Basically, you can set debugger breakpoints to either suspend all threads (in which case the H2 server will suspend too) or only the current thread - with this being the setting you are looking for, the H2 server will continue running.

E.g. if you are using IntelliJ, you right-click the break point (or Ctrl + Shift + F8 to open the "Breakpoints" dialog window) and set "Suspend Thread"

Answer (score 1):

As Pawel Os. mentioned suspending just a thread with combination of using AUTO_SERVER option works fine! My Spring boot configuration looks like this:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:~/test:testdb;AUTO_SERVER=TRUE
spring.datasource.driverClassName=org.h2.Driver
spring.datasource.username=sa
spring.datasource.password=password
```

And intelliJ db configuration like this:

[image: IntelliJ db connection configuration frame]